# Conditional Density Plot using 2 level factor variable

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot Conditional Density Plot using 2 level factor variable. This variable was originally a 3 level factor variable but I have constructed my dataframe (microtus.train) using only 2 of the 3 factor levels. When I plot the conditional density plot, factor level in "y-axis" shows as "unknown" which is the level that I have excluded as I constructed "microtus.train". Please see the plot below.

[image]

I am not sure why it still remains. Can someone please guide me how to fix this? After the fix, I should see "multiplex" and "subterraneus" as labels in the y-axis.

My code is below:

```
library(Flury)
data(microtus, package = "Flury")

# Creating training data frame
microtus.train <- subset(microtus, 
  microtus$Group %in% c("multiplex", "subterraneus"), 
  select = c("Group", "M1Left", "M2Left", "M3Left", "Foramen", "Pbone",
             "Length", "Height", "Rostrum") )
# Plot Conditional Density plot of Group given M1Left
cdplot (Group ~ M1Left, data = microtus.train)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've removed the rows corresponding to the third level of `Group`, however, the `Group` column is still coded as a factor with three levels (only two of which are now present in the data), which appears to confuse the `cdplot` function. Use `droplevels` to remove the empty level.

```
str(microtus.train$Group)
```

> ```
> Factor w/ 3 levels "multiplex","subterraneus",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> ```

```
microtus.train$Group = droplevels(microtus.train$Group)
str(microtus.train$Group)
```

> ```
> Factor w/ 2 levels "multiplex","subterraneus": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> ```

```
# Plot Conditional Density plot of Group given M1Left
cdplot (Group ~ M1Left, data = microtus.train)
```

[image]